# Django edit and update data with MySql

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In my website, each user has their own login id and password, so if a user is logged in, he can add, edit and update his record only.

models.py is

```
class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def profile(request):      
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        reportform = ReportForm(request.POST)

        if reportform.is_valid():
            report = reportform.save(commit=False)
            report.user = request.user
            report.save()
            return redirect('/index/')

    else:
        report = Report.objects.get()
        reportform = ReportForm(instance=report)

    return render_to_response('report/index.html',
                   { 'form': reportform, },
                   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

A user should have one age and it should be in one row of data in the database.

1. If there is no data in the database, i.e if it's a first time for the user, it is allowed to for the user to insert data into the database.
2. If the user reopens a page, the data that was inserted should be shown in editable mode.

It is just like the scenario *"if a new user creates a gmail account, he can create the account at the first time and again he can only edit and update their details"*.The same procedure i want to implement in my website.

I tried it with above code, I am not able to insert the data in the database. I tried with direct insertion in mysql db and checked, so the inserted data i can see in editable mode but if i change that and save, it is creating another row of data in db.

Then if I am going to insert it for first time, I am getting the following trace back.

```
Environment:    

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.100.10/report/index/

Django Version: 1.3.7
Python Version: 2.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'south',
 'collect',
 'incident',
 'report_settings']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/root/Projects/ir/incident/views.py" in when
  559.         report = Report.objects.get()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
  132.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  349.                     % self.model._meta.object_name)

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at report/index/
Exception Value: Report matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've shown, your most likely issue is that the `Report` did not get saved to the database. You haven't said anything about the `ReportForm` you are using, or the data that is used with that, but most likely the following part is never executed:

```
if reportform.is_valid():
    report = reportform.save(commit=False)
    (...)
```

Hence, no report is ever saved. Because of this, when you reach this line:

```
report = Report.objects.get()
```

... you will get the traceback you mention. I'd recommend replacing the `.get()` with either `.all()` or `.filter()`, as they won't throw an exception when there are no matching results.

For updating the data, you should first get the report instance from the database, and pass that to the form's `save` function:

```
report = Report.objects.filter(name=some_value)
report.user = request.user
reportform.save(instance=report)
```

Comment: I applied the changes in view as u said,but it shown some error,partially i cleared now i am facing the following error (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")

Comment: That implies that the `report.user = request.user` line was not executed.

Comment: I suggest you try it from the shell first. Create a new `Report` manually, fill it's fields with data, and save it. Then, see if you can retrieve it via the `.get()` function. If that works, migrate that code to your view function.

Answer (score 0):

```
report = Report.objects.get()
reportform = ReportForm(instance=report)
```

I tried to run an empty .get() in one of my examples and it gave me similar error. 
if you are trying to get all entities try all since get only will let u return one unique item:

```
report = Report.ojbects.all()
```